# Android - SQLite Create database file from existing database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an application that has a database (created and populated within the application). What I would like to do is to be able to create a new database (while keeping the original one) and upload the new database. The new database is based on a table in the original one.

I already have code for uploading a file to a folder in my web server. I also have successfully created a new table based on an existing database table using the `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table` SQLite command.

However, I want to create an entire new database and not just another table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167 to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Uhh, no. I already have a database IN the application. I just want to create a new one based on the original one. The question you linked is for packaging a database with an application.

Comment: Why can't you just copy the database file?

Comment: The database file can be large and I don't want to upload all that. There will be scenarios wherein I would only want a part of it uploaded.